# How to add a file select input in NSIS script?

Tags: windows-installer, nsis

I am creating a windows installer using NSIS. In this installer, on one page I want to request user to add a license file using license file-input. If the license file is valid then user will be able to proceed else an error message will be thrown. But during creation of build itself, I am getting an error. Please refer my following code and error:

```
Function LicenseWarning

  !insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT "License Warning" ""
    nsDialogs::Create 1018
    Pop $LicenseWarningDialog

    ${If} $LicenseWarningDialog == error
        Abort
    ${EndIf}

    ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 20u "This version of QMF Vision requires license for activation. Ensure you have the license file available or contact your administrator."
    Pop $LicenseWarningMsg

  ${NSD_CreateGroupBox} 2u 70u 295u 38u "Select License File"
  ${NSD_CreateFileRequest} 10u 85u 210u 12u ""
  Pop $LicenseFileInput
  ${NSD_CreateBrowseButton} 228u 83u 55u 14u "Browse..."
  Pop $BrowseButton
  ${NSD_OnClick} $BrowseButton OnBrowseForLicense
  ${NSD_SetText} $LicenseFileInput $LicenseFile

    nsDialogs::Show

FunctionEnd

Function OnBrowseForLicense

  nsDialogs::SelectFileDialog open "" "*.lic" 
  Pop $0

  ${If} $0 != ""
    ${GetFileName} $0 $1
    ${If} $1 == "license.lic"
      StrCpy $LicenseFile $0
      ${NSD_SetText} $LicenseFileInput $0
      SetOutPath $INSTDIR\data
      IfFileExists $LicenseFile 0 file_not_found
        File $LicenseFile  <= On this line I am getting an error
      file_not_found:
    ${Else}
      MessageBox MB_ICONINFORMATION|MB_OK "License file is invalid."
      Abort
    ${EndIf}
  ${EndIf}

FunctionEnd
```

Error:

```
File: "$LicenseFile" -> no files found.
Usage: File [/nonfatal] [/a] ([/r] [/x filespec [...]] filespec [...] |
   /oname=outfile one_file_only)
```

Please help me solve it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `File` instruction is used to compress files into the installer and can only be used on the machine where you are compiling the installer.

Use [`FileOpen`](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/Chapter4.html#fileinst) and `FileRead` to parse files on the users system. Use `CopyFiles /silent /filesonly $LicenseFile $InstDir` if you want to copy the chosen file to the installation directory.

Having the license check in your application instead of the installer is probably a better idea...

Comment: I want to add the license file in the installation directory as it is just like file-upload-input in HTML. I have tried the hard coded file and the code is working fine. Check the code for 'Simply install a file' at [link](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Simple_tutorials).

Comment: You cannot add files to the installer on a custom page. You can copy a file from A to B though.

Comment: Yes, I want to copy from A to B. But in this case B location will be defined in the installer script as $INSTDIR\data and A location will be added by user while installing through ${NSD_CreateFileRequest}.

Comment: That is not a problem. See the edit of my answer.